# Matrix equation

Tags: matrices

I would like to know if there is a way to resolve an equation such as this one:
$$
(\begin{matrix}
a_{11} &  a_{12}  & a_{13}
\end{matrix})
\times
(\begin{matrix}
b_{11} \\
b_{21} \\
b_{31}
\end{matrix})
=
(\begin{matrix}0\end{matrix})
$$
Where we only know $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$ and $a_{13}$ ?
I guess there are can be an infinity of solutions, starting with all elements of B being equal to zero. But I would like to know what would be the way to find one, if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying the matrix product, this equality comes down to:

$a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31}=0$

Assuming that we know all the $a$'s, we may choose $b_{21}=s$ and $b_{31}=t$ where $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ are "free-variables".

So we get:

- $b_{11}=\frac{-a_{12}s-a_{13}t}{a_{11}}$
- $b_{21}=s$
- $b_{31}=t$

Hence all the solution to that problem are vectors of the form $(b_{11},b_{21},b_{31})=s(-\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}},1,0)+t(-\frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}},0,1)$ where $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Alright, as I feared there is an infinity of solutions then. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's usually the case when you have more unknown variables than equations that control the possible solutions.

Comment: Btw, you may handle the cases seperately if some of the $a$'s equal zero. If $a_{11}=0$, then $b_{11}$ has no control at all. You may repeat the above reasoning and get all possible solutions by choosing only one "free-variable" $b_{31}=t$.  Similarly to any other $a$ being zero. If two $a$'s are zero, then those corresponding $b$'s have no control and can be anything. The remaining $b$ must be zero though. If all $a$'s are zero, then all values for $b$'s satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a dot product of vectors $(a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13})$ and $(b_{11}, b_{21}, b_{31})$ in three-dimensional space. A dot product is zero when the two vectors are orthogonal (i.e. at right angles), so if the $a$ vector is nonzero, the $b$ vector may lie anywhere in the plane it is perpendicular to; of course if the $a$ vector is zero, the $b$ vector can be anything at all.